# React-Hook Form useFieldArray: Adding Material-UI Select shows no data in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a Material-UI Select inside a nested `useFieldArray`. Every time I'll add the Material-UI Select and submit it to the form, whatever values that were entered in the form will not be saved and do not log in to the console. Also, I keep on having this warning when I do not have a `ref` anymore.

Link to codesandbox where codes are complete here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-nested-arrays-forked-vjwbp?file=/src/nestedFieldArray.js:0-1722

> Warning: Invalid value for prop `refer` on  tag. Either remove it
> from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the
> DOM.

Material-UI select

```
import { InputLabel, MenuItem, FormControl, Select } from "@mui/material";

const Size = ({ name, refer, defaultValue }) => {
  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth variant="filled">
      <InputLabel id="Size Label">Size</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="Size"
        id="size"
        name={name}
        label="Product"
        refer={refer}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
      >
        <MenuItem value="S">Small</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="M">Medium</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="L">Large</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default Size;
```

**I'm using the `Size` here:**

```
import React from "react";
import { useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import Size from "./Drop_drowns/Size";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

export default ({ nestIndex, control, register }) => {
  const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: `test[${nestIndex}].nestedArray`
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {fields.map((item, k) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.id} style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
            <label>Colors:</label>
            <Size
              name={`test[${nestIndex}].nestedArray[${k}].field1`}
              refer={register({ required: true })}
              defaultValue={item.field1}
              style={{ marginRight: "25px" }}
            />
            {/* <input
              name={`test[${nestIndex}].nestedArray[${k}].field1`}
              ref={register({ required: true })}
              defaultValue={item.field1}
              style={{ marginRight: "25px" }}
            /> */}

            <TextField
              name={`test[${nestIndex}].nestedArray[${k}].field2`}
              refer={register()}
              defaultValue={item.field2}
            />

            <TextField
              name={`test[${nestIndex}].nestedArray[${k}].field3`}
              refer={register()}
              defaultValue={item.field3}
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(k)}>
              Delete Colors
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() =>
          append({
            field1: "field1",
            field2: "field2"
          })
        }
      >
        Add Colors
      </button>

      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you solve this?